# Uncaught ReferenceError: mat4 is not defined even gl-Matrix library is downloaded

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, transformation, gl-matrix

I am building a 2d graphics engine using webgl, JavaScript and HTML, I wanted the gl-Matrix.js graphics library to do transformations so, I downloaded the lg-Matrix library zip file from their website [https://glmatrix.net](https://glmatrix.net/) and extracted it into a folder called `lib` in my project. I didn't forgot to add the `.js` file to the HTML file using a `script tag`

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/lib/toji-gl-matrix-0bca31a/dist/gl-matrix.js"></script>
```

Then I call some `lg-Matrix` functions as follows.

```js
    var xform = mat4.create();
    mat4.translate(xform, xform, vec3.fromValues(-0.25, 0.25, 0.0));
    mat4.rotateZ(xform, xform, 0.2); 
    mat4.scale(xform, xform, vec3.fromValues(1.2, 1.2, 1.0));
    
    this.mWhiteSq.draw(xform);
```

`this.mWhiteSq` is a function that draws a white square to the middle of the canvas, It is also applies the given transformations.

The problem is JavaScript console in the browser prints the error massage mentioned in the title. It says that mat4 is not defined.

Comment: what is your folder structure? is src pointing to the correct folder?

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV yes

Answer (score 2):

Hey I just discovered that the problem can be solved by using `glMatrix.mat4.create()` instead of just using `mat4.create()`. It's the same for every other function.